# Getting the Image Source from an HTMLImageElement object

Tags: jquery

I have the following jQuery which I want to output a list of images. The problem is that I cannot get 'this' to find the source. It currently is an object which outputs as an HTMLImageElement. How can I get the image source from this object?

```
$("#imgs li.images img").each(function(i) { 
    $("#list").append("<li><img src=\""+this.attr("src")+"\" /></li>");
});
```

I currently get the error that this.attr is not a function.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`this` is the DOMNode, not a jQuery object. You can access `this.src` immediately, or, if you want to use jQuery, `$(this).attr('src')`, although would be a detour for doing the same thing.

Comment: arrgh figured it was something small that I was overlooking.

Comment: NB: the two methods are not equivalent. While the jQuery method does `this.getAttribute('src')` and thus gets the attribute as given in the markup, `this.src` is processed and usually an absolute(r) address (with protocol, domain, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

Use `$(this)` instead of `this`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your use of 'this'. It is a special keyword used in object orientated programming to refer to an objects own properties